# Improve the performance of PLSQL code when the source data is large?

Tags: plsql

This PLSQL code will run and produces correct results, but is very slow when the source table is large, how can this be  rewritten to improve performance?

```
for data_row in (select * from &lt;large_source_table&gt; )

loop

begin

select &#39;Y&#39;

into l_exists

from &lt;lookup_table&gt;

where &lt;lookup_table&gt;.pk = data_row.&lt;column&gt;;

exception

when no_data_found then

l_ exists:= &#39;N&#39;;

end;

if (l_ exists = &#39;Y&#39;)

then

insert into &lt;destination_table&gt; values (…);

else

insert into &lt;error_table&gt; values(…);

end if;

end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Processing large data sets row-by-row in PL/SQL is very inefficient - search "Oracle context switch" for the reasons behind this.  Often the solution is bulk processing - there's lots of information out there about this, for example [this from the Oracle magazine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html)

However, in your case you should be able to use the fastest method of all, just using SQL statements in your procedure.  First insert rows where lookup values exist :

```
INSERT INTO destination_table
(SELECT 
  ...
FROM 
 large_source_table
,lookup_table
WHERE ...
)
```

Then insert values where no lookup exists

```
INSERT INTO error_table
(SELECT 
  ...
FROM 
 large_source_table
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SQL that joins to your lookup table)
)
```

Two SQL statements that will run as fast as your database will allow...

Hope that helps